# linux cmd how to delete all the file of a folder that don't have any permissions for the category owner,read,write,execute

Tags: command-line, delete

In linux command prompt i have a folder that has about 10 files that different permissions how do i delete everyone that don't have permissions for the owner, to read ,write or execute in one command ?

Comment: So the owner has 0 permission? this sounds like a somewhat artificial situation - is it a homework exercise? Have you read `man find` - in particular the `-perm` section?

Comment: these are files the the owner cannot manipulate so we need to delete them

Comment: If you have write (`w`) access to the parent directory, you can delete the contents. Or use `sudo`. Read `man sudo`

Comment: not all the files need to be deleted only those in which i dont have permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-perm` test of the `find` command to identify files by their permissions. In particular,

> ```
>    -perm /mode
>           Any  of the permission bits mode are set for the file.
> ```

So for example, given

```
$ ls -l subdir
total 0
----r--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 0 Oct 15 19:15 file0
---xr--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 0 Oct 15 19:15 file1
--w-r--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 0 Oct 15 19:15 file2
--wxr--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 0 Oct 15 19:15 file3
-r--r--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 0 Oct 15 19:15 file4
-r-xr--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 0 Oct 15 19:15 file5
-rw-r--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 0 Oct 15 19:15 file6
-rwxr--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 0 Oct 15 19:15 file7
```

then

```
$ find subdir ! -perm /u=rwx
subdir/file0
```

finds the file that has neither read, write, nor execute permission for its owner.

Once you are happy that it is identifying the correct files, you can add `-delete` to the command to delete them:

```
find subdir ! -perm /u=rwx -delete
```

You can use octal `700` in place of symbolic `u=rwx` if you prefer.