# Delete files with no permissions only (read, write and execute)

Tags: command-line, permissions, delete, find

I have a directory, named `data`, with multiples files in it which have different types of permissions. I want to delete only the files that do not have any permissions, i.e shown as `----------` in `ls -l`. My guess is to use the `find` command, but I don't know where to start.

What one line command can do this ?

Comment: Related: [linux cmd how to delete all the file of a folder that don't have any permissions for the category owner,read,write,execute](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284160/linux-cmd-how-to-delete-all-the-file-of-a-folder-that-dont-have-any-permissions)

Comment: Awesome ! That's it.. thank you @steeldriver

Comment: That's not *quite* it (hence why I said "related"" not "duplicate") - please see the answer below for your specific case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete files with no permissions (read, write and execute)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285827/delete-files-with-no-permissions-read-write-and-execute)

Comment: @karel I think that the target should be closed as a duplicate of this question, because the target mentions a confusing thing about using `chmod -R 777 data` to change the permissions of all files in the directory.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog That's not so bad because `chmod -R 777 data` is only in the question, and the author Neo Capo wouldn't have asked the question if he already knew everything about the answer. The deal breaker for me is I think that the answer to the other question is a bit better.

Answer (score 4):

The `find` command you are looking for is this:

```
find /path/to/data -type f -perm 000 -delete
```

**Caution:** First run the above command without `-delete` to make sure that it lists the correct files.

- `-type f` lists files only.
- `-perm 000` lists items without permissions only (`000` is "no permissions" in [octal mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Numerical_permissions)).
- `-delete` deletes the found items.

See [`man find`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/find.1.html) for more options.